# record types that weren't found for a specific value in oracle query

Tags: oracle11g

I have this query

```
Select distinct p_id, p_date,p_city 
  from p_master 
 where p_a_id in(1,2,5,8,2,1,10,02)
```

and my `IN` clause contains 200 values. How do I get to know which ones weren't returned by the query.  Each value in the `IN` clause may have a record in some cases they don't. I want to know all the records that weren't found for any selected `p_a_id` type.

Please help

Comment: :Write another query with `NOT IN `clause  with same input paramater :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick but I'm sure there's an easier way to find this out :-)

```
with test1 as 
(select '1,2,5,8,2,1,10,02' str from dual)
select * from (
select trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) cols 
   from test1 t, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(t.str,',','</e><e>')|| '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x) cols 
   left outer join 
 (Select count(*), p_a_id from p_master where p_a_id in (1,2,5,8,2,1,10,02) group by p_a_id) p
 on p.p_a_id = cols.cols
 where p_a_id is null
 ;
```